# How to disable page scroll when keyboard pops up

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I have a web site with an input field.

When the input field is focused, the iPad keyboard shows up and the page scrolls up automatically.  When the keyboard is dismissed, there's no scrolling back to the original position.

Is it possible to programatically disable this behavior (the scrolling) using javascript and/or css ?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? It would make handling events easier. If not then bind to `onfocus` event of the textarea, save the current body or window scroll position and then `onblur` scroll back to the saved position. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure whether the `onfocus` event on iPad is fired before the keyboard shows up or after. You have to test it yourself :)

Comment: To determine the current position, have a look at [this Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html). To scroll a page back programmatically, see the documentation for the [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollTo) function at MDN.